# Return an Array from SQL Query Result

Tags: javascript

I don't think it matters, but I'm using PostgresSQL and have this query:

```sql
SELECT
  f.superhero_id,
    COUNT(*) AS superhero_follow_count
FROM
  follows AS f
WHERE
  f.active = TRUE
GROUP BY
  superhero_id
ORDER BY
  superhero_id ASC
```

Which gives me results in PostgreSQL like this:

| superhero_id | superhero_follow_count |
| --- | --- |
| 298 | 1 |
| 301 | 1 |
| 302 | 1 |
| 490 | 2 |

And with the results, I want to return an object like this:

```
const heroFollows = {
  298: 1
  301: 1
  302: 1
  490: 2
}
```

I know how to code it if I do a loop, but I think there's a more efficient way to do it, that I just don't know how to code, yet. This method:

```
user.heroAllUsersFollowedIds = allUsersHeroFollowsRes.rows.map(
        (c) => c.superhero_id
    );
```

... just returns an array of the superhero_id values, without the counts. Is it possible to build an object like I've described above in just a line or two of code from the query results?

Comment: Why avoid a loop? Javascript is fast. Unless there is a noticeable performance issue, just use a loop and call it a day. Premature optimizations will only slow you down. Pun intended.